# Can i add more than 5 menu items in bottom navigation view?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I am trying to add more then 5 items in bottom navigation view but its causing inflate error.

Comment: kindly share your code you have done yet so far

Comment: for more than 5 items, BottomNavigation is not a good choice rather you should choose Tabs with pager

Answer (score 10):

According to Google's Material Design specification, BottomNavigationView does not support more than 5 items. You can use another library for BottomNavigationView since you can't achieve this with Google's library.

> Create a menu resource with up to 5 navigation targets (BottomNavigationView does not support more than 5 items).
>   https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-navigation-view/

Secondly, Having 5 or more items in BottomNavigation is a bad design in terms of User Experience. Even 4 is a stretch. If you need more than 5 items, BottomNavigation is not suitable for you.

Comment: `Having 5 or more items in BottomNavigation is a bad design in terms of User Experience. Even 4 is a stretch.` — This answer seems awfully dogmatic without providing heuristics, evidence, or proof. 

What is bad about, e.g., [this AirBnB screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V91zZ.jpg)?

Answer (score 3):

According to Material Design Specification, it is a bad practice to use more than 5 `menu` items for `BottomNavigationView`. Since, it is used to show **only 3 to 5 top-level destinations(not related to same subject but of equal importance)**, I suggest you to use [`Navigation Drawer`](https://material.io/components/navigation-drawer) instead. Also, I would only recommend you to use `Tab Layout with ViewPager`, if the destinations are connected to a common subject.

To illustrate it further, let's assume there is a `Pill Reminder` app. The related destinations can be `Pending`, `Completed` and/or `Missed` which are related in a way that they all show status of all `Reminder` at a point of time. To show these information, I would use `ViewPager with TabLayout`.
For other destinations such as `Settings`, `Nearby Pharmacies`, etc. which are top-level, I would use `NavigationDrawer`.

Comment: Sorry for the late response @cbg_pandey. But the issue is that when you want to build dynamic layouts there is enough space on a tablet to show more. So I do not fully agree with the assessment on Google's end. They should let developers decide.

Answer (score 2):

If you want that then u can take a Horizontal linear layout in that take the horizontal scroll and then take textview or button as much u like.

Answer (score 1):

Currently (2023), you can have more than 5 items in bottom navigation view as explained here (emphasis mine):

> We have design concerns around allowing more items than 5. If you
> really need that, **you can extend BottomNavigationView and override
> getMaxItemCount() to provide a different value than 5**.

source: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/543#issuecomment-881579335

BUT take into account that it will only work from version 1.8.0 and up

source: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/pull/2923